# SQL Workbench: Migration of Ms Access RDBMS to SQL; Operation Cancelled

Tags: sql, ms-access, migration, mysql-workbench

I have an RDBM which needs to be converted to MySQL. I would like to open the database with Workbench and get a file to someone. However every time I run the migration wizard for a Microsoft Access RDBM, ODBC data source parameter, and then find the data source to migrate, it simply just blocks the process on the test, saying:

```
"Test Source DBMS Connection:
Operation Cancelled"
```

The RDBM is either type .mdf, .accd or 5.3 ANSI. None allow a connection. I have searched Oracle and other sources online with very few hints or clues as to why this happens to my database. The only other alternative is buy some expensive conversion software. Please help! I have not a clue what information might be of use to me to solve this problem. I have used the standard Oracle/MySQL tutorial: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-migration-database-access.html

Also to note I have tried disabling all firewalls. And the general ODBC connections I make just quit working, saying in various ways they cannot connect. Any resources to point me to that might be helpful with some more basics on this?

I also found this resource which explains why certain pipe connections are not working for ODBC: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/can-not-connect-to-server.html It lists some command prompts which I am uncertain how to use or where to enter. I tried running these as admin on a standard cmd but they just say command not recognized.

Comment: Can you provide full debug log from Wokbench (run Workbench with --log-level=debug3)?

Comment: We kind of worked around it, but thanks.

Comment: What was the workaround ??

Answer (score 1):

I've just encountered the same issue while testing out the MySQL workbench software.

I had installed the 64-bit version of MySQL Workbench. However, I only had 32-bit Access, and so the ODBC drivers were all 32-bit.   Uninstalling and installing 32-bit version of MySQL solved this issue and let me connect to my local Access database for migration. (download 32-bit installer from here: https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/)

I know you found a work-around, but if you wanted to go back to Workbench, checking that you are using all 32-bit (or all 64-bit) software & drivers might help.

Cheers,
Dave.

Answer (score 0):

On "System DSN" (32 bit) press Add select Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb,*.accdb), press Finish, On setup page press 'select' and map to the database you want to connect to and click on the database on left pan click ok. add database name and press OK. close the window. now you can use ODBC for access in MYSQL(32 bit).